# Autoselect and jQuery post doesnt work together

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, post

I have another problem with my code.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#wojewodz").change(function(){
        var id_wojewodztwa = $("#wojewodz").children(":selected").attr("id");
        $.post("miasta.php", { id_wojewodztwa: id_wojewodztwa } );
        $('#powiat_miasto_auto_complete').autocomplete({source:'miasta.php', minLength:2});
        });
    </script>
```

this is functions which get ID of selected select and transfering it to miasta.php

```
$options = array(
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8',
); 

try {
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass, $options);
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

$return_arr = array();

if (($conn) and (isset($_GET['id_wojewodztwa'])))
{
    $id_wojewodztwa = $_GET['id_wojewodztwa'];
    $ac_term = "%".$_GET['term']."%";
    $query = "SELECT DISTINCT nazwa FROM podzial_tm where woj='$id_wojewodztwa' and nazdod!='województwo' and nazwa like :term LIMIT 10";
    $result = $conn->prepare($query);
    $result->bindValue(":term",$ac_term);
    $result->execute();

    /* Retrieve and store in array the results of the query.*/
    while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $row_array['value'] = $row['nazwa'];

        array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
    }


}
/* Free connection resources. */
$conn = null; 
/* Toss back results as json encoded array. */
echo json_encode($return_arr);
?>
```

somebody can tell me where is some mistake? 
when i change " where woj='$id_wojewodztwa'" to for example " where woj='26'" and delete " and (isset($_GET['id_wojewodztwa']))" everything is ok, so i think i have problem with POST

happy Easter! :)))

Answer (score 3):

You are POSTing the data.  You need to look in `$_POST['id_wojewodztwa']` for the value you are looking for, not in `$_GET`.

Comment: wait a moment.. when I'm posting data to miasta.php, in miasta.php I must to get it? am I right?

Comment: @DawidGórecki you are using jquery post `$.post("miasta.php"`

Comment: `$_GET` holds values passed to PHP for HTTP GET requests via URL query string.  `$_POST` holds values passed to PHP for HTTP POST requests when data is posted in a form-encoded manner.  POST data resides in `$_POST`.  This is PHP 101, so you ought to go to PHP site and read up on how these superglobals are populated. Also it sounds like you should read up on basic HTTP protocol to understand the difference between GET and POST (and other action verbs like PUT, and DELETE which are typically not used by browsers but are useful to know about for modern RESTful web services)

Comment: @MikeBrant, kindly, i think you are in mistake, we can use `$_GET`

Comment: @Amir You can use HTTP GET to do this, but your code sample shows you using POST (via the `$.post()` method).

Answer (score 1):

```
$.post("miasta.php", { id_wojewodztwa: id_wojewodztwa } );
```

to

```
$.get("miasta.php", { id_wojewodztwa: id_wojewodztwa } );
```

or if you have to catch up the result, use:

```
$.get("miasta.php", { id_wojewodztwa: id_wojewodztwa },function(result){
       /** some code here */
},'json');
```

**UPDATE:**

if you use $.post, edit the following lines:

```
if (($conn) and (isset($_POST['id_wojewodztwa'])))
{
    $id_wojewodztwa = $_POST['id_wojewodztwa'];
```

Comment: I have $.post("miasta.php", { id_wojewodztwa: id_wojewodztwa } ); and $id_wojewodztwa = $_POST['id_wojewodztwa'];, the autocomplete still no have any results.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `isset($_GET['id_wojewodztwa'])` and also modify `$id_wojewodztwa = intval($_GET['id_wojewodztwa']);`